# ASP.NET MVC : saving related entities on form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I require a little bit of help with ASP.NET MVC data entry. Can anybody help me how would I save a new product that is automatically tied to a catalog? It is a requirement that the product can not be created without a catalog. But I can save the product only without the catalog, and this is what I got so far:

Entities:

[image: Entities]

The Model:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.ProductsInCatalog = new HashSet<ProductsInCatalog>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductsInCatalog> ProductsInCatalog { get; set; }
}
public partial class Catalog
{
    public Catalog()
    {
        this.ProductsInCatalog = new HashSet<ProductsInCatalog>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductsInCatalog> ProductsInCatalog { get; set; }
}
public partial class ProductsInCatalog
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CatalogId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Catalog Catalog { get; set; }
}
```

The Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    CatalogManager catalogManager = new CatalogManager();
    ViewBag.Catalogs = catalogManager.GetCatalogs();
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Save")]
public ActionResult Save(EURIS.Entities.Product product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ProductManager productManager = new ProductManager();
        productManager.SaveProduct(product);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The EFCore Manager:

```
 public class ProductManager
{
    readonly LocalDbEntities _context = new LocalDbEntities();

    public List<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        var products = (from item in _context.Product select item).ToList();
        return products;
    }
    public Product GetProductByID(int productID)
    {
        return _context.Product.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == productID);
    }
    public bool SaveProduct(Product product)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Product.Add(product);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception exe)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool DeleteProduct(int productID)
    {
        try
        {
            Product product = _context.Product.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == productID);
            _context.Product.Remove(product);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception exe)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool UpdateProduct(Product product)
    {
        try
        {
            Product prodToUpdate = _context.Product.Where(p => p.Id == product.Id).FirstOrDefault();

            if (prodToUpdate != null)
            {
                _context.Entry(prodToUpdate).CurrentValues.SetValues(product);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (System.Exception exe)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The View:

```
@model EURIS.Entities.Product


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", "Product")
</p>

<table>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Code</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Code)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Catalog asoiation:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="ddlCatalog" onchange="onCatDdlChange">
                    @foreach (EURIS.Entities.Catalog cat in ViewBag.Catalogs)
                    {
                        <option value="@cat.Id">@cat.Code</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit">Save</button></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: you have to show your productmanager class

Comment: Tnx for the info complety forgot, was in a hurry. It has been eddited, its under The EFCore Manager: